# Python/Scrapy question: How to get cleaner results?

Tags: python, data-mining, pipeline, scrapy

My task for a project is to data mine a website for specific names. My experience with python isn't high. When I scraped all the names, they come out in this format:

[u'Bob Joe']
[u'Tim Tom']
[u'Anne Frank']
[u'superman']

How can I clean up these values? What does the 'u' signify? Is my xpath wrong? Would I have to clean it up in a scrapy pipeline (I'd like to avoid this)? I just want the names and not the extra junk around it.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, the 'u' prefix indicates that it's a Unicode string. `[u'Bob Joe']` is a list containing a Unicode string.

Comment: Could you explain how to remove the prefix? So that if I typed    
  
print item.name  
    
it would print out solely the name? I'm sorry if this question is really rudimentary but I am new python and I'm under time constraints which prevents me from being able to adequately dedicate time to learning the language.

Comment: It's a list. Try printing the zeroth element of the list, ie the string: `print item.name[0]`.